# How to include 3rd party API in MVC 5 - Riot Games

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, curl

I am making a site and I would like to try and pull some user data via a Developer API.

I have never done this before, and I am not sure how to really search for a solution. All I know is that I think I should use AJAX and that I need to make sure it is cross-domain compatible.

The game I am making a stat page for is League of Legends, and they have an API in order to pull their information in JSON format: https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/getting-started

Their example uses this, which does: *a cURL request loads RiotSchmick's basic summoner object in JSON.*

`curl --request GET 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=<key>' --include`

What I am wondering is if someone could show me a very simple way to include this within my MVC project, like a simple **View** that contains a single `div` that will update with RiotSchmick's user data, and then the **AJAX/JSON** call that does this magic. You can ignore the `<key>` since I assume I just plug my key into that location.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beginning `asp.net json from url` and `jquery json parse` keywords will help you.

I got started before this API but I didn't continue.

Of course you can only download string on your controller via webclient etc and parse it javascript/framework on your view.

Use your own; Controller name, Model namespace and API key

**MODEL**

```
Public Class SummonerModel

 Public Property ID As Integer
 Public Property Name As String
 Public Property ProfileIconId As Integer
 Public Property SummonerLevel As Integer
 Public Property RevisionDate As String
 Public Property ErrorMessage As String

End Class
```

**VIEW**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of MP.Web.Models.Site.SummonerModel)" %>

<div id="SummonerResult">
<%If Model.ErrorMessage = "" Then%>

ID : <%=Model.ID%><br />
Name : <%=Model.Name%><br />
Profile Icon Id : <%=Model.ProfileIconId%><br />
Revision Date : <%=Model.RevisionDate%><br />
SummonerLevel : <%=Model.SummonerLevel%><br />

<%Else%>

Error / <%=Model.ErrorMessage%>

<%End If%>

</div>
```

**CONTROLLER **

```
Function GetSummoner(name As String) As PartialViewResult

    Dim model = New SummonerModel

    Dim url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" & name & "?api_key=<key>"

    Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient()

        Try

            Dim json = webClient.DownloadString(url)

            Dim dic = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, SummonerModel))(json)

            model = dic.FirstOrDefault.Value

        Catch ex As Exception

            model.ErrorMessage = ex.Message

        End Try

    End Using


    Return PartialView(model)

End Function
```

**SCRIPT**

```
setInterval(function () { $("#SummonerResult").load("/RiotGamesApi/GetSummoner?name=RiotSchmick") }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall take a look at this sometime in the next day or two and let ya know how it goes. :)

Comment: @Austin you're welcome, it's working example dont forget to change names. you can integrate other api methods with same ways. get it and parse it. good luck